# Obtaining Email Through Twitter Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 with external authentication providers.
 I manage to retrieve emails through standard scopes out of all major platforms Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, but Twitter.

Twitter requires special permission to allow "verifying" user's details (e.g. email) through additional Twitter API call.
 In order to perform such a call, we need to utilize Twitter access token and Twitter access token secret that passed through `TwitterAuthenticatedContext`.

*Question:
What would be the right place to perform such a call?*

Should it be `OnAuthenticated` delegate in `TwitterAuthenticationProvider`? 
 Although, it might become a performance bottleneck, because it'll happen all the time regardless whether we've already obtained user's email.

What alternatives might be valid?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the twitter token and secret via claims to your user service (in `OnAuthenticated`).

The in the user service you can determine if you actually need to make that additional roundtrip to twitter or not.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Practically, you suggest to use claims as a transport for passing data from one internal mechanism - `Authentication Provider`, to another - `User Service`. Does it imply claims removal after `User Service`

Comment: Yes. You create a new identity for the client anyways.